# Question about delayed sampled sinusoid math expression

Tags: math, delay

I have been studying the digital audio processing by using the book <Designing Audio Effect Plugins in C++>.

For analog Sinusoid:

Complex Sinusoid = $e^{jωt}$

Delayed Sinusoid = $e^{jω(t−n)} = e^{jwt} * e^{-jwn}$, a delay of n seconds

For digital sampled version:

sampled complex sinusoid = $e^{jωnT}$, T is interval for each sample, n is the index of sample

I understand all above, but I got confused about the delayed sampled sinusoid which described as: $e^{jω ( nT −M )}$, M = samples of delay

But I think it should be described as $e^{jωT( n − M )}$, since the T is a constant for a fixed sample rate, n and M has the same unit.

At first I thought that maybe a typo, but the following computation parts of the book are all using the $e^{jω ( nT −M )}$ as basis.

Anyone can explain it for me?

Comment: i was studying the same book and I agree with your question, i think the author is wrong,  is in "seconds" but M is in unit of samples

Comment: @csguy Hi, I think I figured it out, see my answer posted below.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed a typo

$e^{j \omega ((n - k)T)}$ would be the delay for $k$ samples, the $M$ in the expression $e^{j \omega(nT - M)}$ is the delay (in seconds if $\omega$ is in $rad/s$)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an incorrect notation.

When a function of time is sampled, $t = nT_s$ is considered where $n$ is the sample index and $T_s$ is the sampling period.

Generally, if a function of time is given as e.g. $x(t)$, the sampled function is written as $x[n]$ rather than $x(nT_s)$ but this is an acceptable notation too.

In the case of the given exponential function, let’s say $y(t) = e^{j{\omega}t}$, the sampled function will be $y[n] = e^{j{\omega}n}$.

If the sample function $y[n]$ is shifted $M$ samples towards the right-hand side of the sample axis for $M>0$, the resultant shifted function becomes $y[n-M] = e^{j{\omega}[n-M]}$.

Alternatively, if both the time and samples are taken into account at the same time, the shifted function can be written down as $y((n-M)T_s) = e^{j{\omega}(n-M)T_s}$.

However, the shifting notation $(nT_s-{M})$ is wrong as in this case, the shifting is done in the time domain as $nT_s$ is still representing a moment in time because $n$ is a constant value and the sampling period is multiplied by a constant. This process results in a moment in the units of seconds, milliseconds, etc.

This incorrect notation is analogous to subtracting a current value from a voltage value.

I prefer to use the sample function notation e.g. $x[n]$ rather than $x(nT_s)$ to minimise confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of you for your replies. I think I got the point: it is a false representation!!!

Let's say delay a signal for M samples.
It definitely should be like this:$e^{jwT(n - M)}$, break it apart to $e^{jwnT} * e^{-jwMT}$

The book wrote like this, $e^{jw(nT - M)}$, and break it apart, it's $e^{jwnT} * e^{-jwM}$

What's wrong with the book is these two w in different exponents do not have the same unit, you can't use the same notation w in a single equation!!!

The first one in $e^{jwnT}$ has unit radians/sec for a specific signal, and the second w has unit radians/sample!!!
From the top equation, $e^{-jwMT}$, we mutiply w(radians/sec) and T, $wT = (2Pi*f) * (1/f_s) = 2Pi*(f/f_s)$ = w(raidans/sample), where f_s is sampleRate.

That's why in the chapter following when he evaluates the transfer function for 1st order feedforward filter:
$H(w) = a_0 + a_1*e^{-jw1}$, the w(radians/sample). For the Nyquist frequency, he substitutes the w by using Pi, because the Nyquist Frequency has Pi(radians/sample) speed of rotation.

Of course, we could stick to using w as radians/sec for the transfer function, it will be like these:
$H(w) = a_0 + a_1*e^{-jw1T}$, the w(radians/sec). For the Nyquist frequency, instead of substituting the w by using pi, we should use $2Pi*f_n = 2Pi*f_s/2 = Pi*f_s = Pi/T$
then put the Pi/T back into the equation, the T in the equation just crossed out!!! So we could get the same result compared with using w(radians/sample).